# How to scrape a table?

Tags: excel, vba

The website I am trying to scrape: https://apps.nl.tele2.nl/zakelijk/postcodecheck/business-extern

It is a tool that scrapes zip codes + availabilities

```vb
Sub Pulldatafromweb()
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    
    Dim ieobj As InternetExplorer
    Dim htmlEle As IHTMLElement
    Dim i As Integer
    
    i = 1
 
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    
    IE.navigate "https://apps.nl.tele2.nl/zakelijk/postcodecheck/business-extern"
    
    Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
    
    Set doc = IE.document
    
    doc.getElementById("postcode").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2").Range("A3").Value
    doc.getElementById("housenumber").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2").Range("b3").Value
    doc.getElementById("submit").Click
    
    For Each htmlelement In ieobj.document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper")(0).getElementsByTagName("TR")
        With ActiveSheet
            .Range("A" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(0).textContent
            .Range("B" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(1).textContent
            .Range("C" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(2).textContent
        End With
        
        i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

It seems there is an issue with the name of the table.

Comment: What problems are you having? Errors? Unexpected results? Can yo supply some sample data, e.g. postcode etc?

Comment: Hi Norie, my aim is that i have a postcode file and that the macro automatically scrapes the outputs of the website's table. Until now I don't get any results nor errors. If i do a debug.print modus at the end it seems to be that the formula is not copying any stuff into my 'immediate' screen nor excel. And I can't figure out why. some sample postcodes are: 2511 BC + 19 as housenumber (=huisnummer), 2521 CC + 60, 1102 DB + 149

Comment: Could anyone help me please?

Comment: Didn't see your comment with the sample data until now. I'll have a look at it in a minute. I can tell you one thing straight away - there are no 'tr' elements in the div with class name 'wrapper'.

Comment: What is it you are trying to scrape from the page?

Comment: Hi Norie, no worries! What I would like to scrape is the table that you get when you insert one of the postal codes. So the site is in Dutch but when you insert e.g. 2511BC + 19 as a postal code and house number and afterwards press enter, I want to scrape the table that shows the results of the postal code-check. This means that I am looking for the dark blue table that states 'netwerk', 'max band breedte' and 'aanvullende informatie' as headers. The other headers plus content is irrelevant.

Comment: I've posted an answer that appears to work.

Comment: Hi Norie, thanks! It seems like I am still doing something wrong. By the time I copy paste your code it keeps saying that I run into error 91. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be looking for the wrong element, the table you want has the classname 'infotable'.

This code returns the data from that table.

```
Sub Pulldatafromweb()
Dim IE As Object
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim ieobj As InternetExplorer
Dim htmlElement As IHTMLElement
Dim i As Long

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True

    IE.navigate "https://apps.nl.tele2.nl/zakelijk/postcodecheck/business-extern"

    Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Set doc = IE.document

    doc.getElementById("postcode").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2").Range("A3").Value
    doc.getElementById("housenumber").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2").Range("b3").Value
    doc.getElementById("submit").Click

    Set doc = IE.document

    For Each htmlElement In doc.getElementsByClassName("infotable")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")
        i = i + 1
        With ActiveSheet
            .Range("A" & i).Value = htmlElement.Children(0).textContent
            .Range("B" & i).Value = htmlElement.Children(1).textContent
            .Range("C" & i).Value = htmlElement.Children(2).textContent
        End With
    Next htmlElement
    
End Sub
```